# Livewire Laravel add dynamic select, how do I resolve the loss of data? Please

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

when add next select, you lose the data of the first select of the municipalities.

**Livewire controller** SelectUsuario.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class SelectUsuario extends Component
{

    public $estados;
    public $estado;
    public $estadoSigla;
    public $municipios;

   public $selects = [];
    public $i = 0;

    public function add($i)
    {
        $i = $i + 1;
        $this->i = $i;
        array_push($this->selects, $i);
    }

    public function remove($i)
    {
        unset($this->selects[$i]);
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->estados = Http::get(
            url("https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados"),
            ['orderBy' => 'nome']
        )->json();
    }

    public function updatedEstadoSigla()
    {
        $this->getMunicipios();
    }


    public function getMunicipios()
    {

       if ($this->estadoSigla != '') {
            foreach ($this->estadoSigla as $estado) {
                $this->municipios = json_decode(
                    Http::get(
                        url("https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados/{$estado}/municipios")
                    )->body(),
                    true
                );
            }

        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.select-usuario');
    }
}
```

**Livewire component** select-usuario.blade.php

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-3"><label>Viagem</label></div>
    <div class="col-3"><label>Seção</label></div>
    <div class="col-4"><label>Funcionário</label></div>
    <div class="col-2"><label>Ação</label></div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <select class="form-control" data-item_id="0">
            <option value="R">Responsável</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <select wire:model="estadoSigla.0" class="form-control" id="estado.0" name="estado.0">
            <option value="">selecione estado...</option>
            @foreach ($this->estados as $estado)
                <option value="{{ $estado['sigla'] }}">{{ $estado['nome'] }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        @if ($this->estadoSigla)
             <select class="form-control" name="municipio.0" id="municipio.0">
                <option value="" selected>selecione município...</option>
                    @foreach ($this->municipios as $municipio)
                        <option value="{{ $municipio['id'] }}">{{ $municipio['nome'] }}</option>
                    @endforeach
            </select>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <button class="btn btn-info mb-2" wire:click.prevent="add({{ $i }})">adicionar</button>
    </div>
    {{-- Add Form --}}
    @foreach ($selects as $key => $value)
        <div class="col-3">
            <select name="item_name[]" class="form-control" data-item_id="{{$value}}">
                <option value="I">Ida</option>
                <option value="V">Volta</option>
                <option value="O">Ida e Volta</option>
                <option value="R">Responsável</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <select wire:model="estadoSigla.{{ $value }}" class="form-control" name="estado.{{ $value }}" id="estado.{{ $value }}">
                <option value="">selecione estado...</option>
                @foreach ($this->estados as $estado)
                <option value="{{ $estado['sigla'] }}">{{ $estado['nome'] }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            @if ($estadoSigla)
                <select class="form-control" name="municipio.{{ $value }}" id="municipio.{{ $value }}">
                    <option value="" selected>selecione município...</option>
                    @foreach ($this->municipios as $municipio)
                            <option value="{{ $municipio['id'] }}">{{ $municipio['nome'] }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <button class="btn btn-dark mb-2" wire:click.prevent="remove({{ $key }})">remover</button>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try adding wire:key directive to the looped select elements while livewire need to keep tracking all the values of them.

```
<select wire:model="estadoSigla.{{ $value }}" class="form-control" id="estado.{{ $value }}" wire:key="estado-select-{{ $key }}"> // or $value, the unique identifier for its
```

also, try adding wire:ignore.self to the root div of the select elements

Comment: I don't know if I did something wrong, but it didn't work. :(

Comment: maybe you must check the getMunicipios() function because whatever select element you are requesting, you're doing it to the same collection of municipios for all, and Livewire on rerender update it too